# How to Trace changes done to memory block allocated on the heap

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I have multithreading program(using ucontext routines) in which I have allocated the stacks for child threads using malloc().Actual problem arises, whenever I try to free the memory allocated for that thread(core dump).
I suspect that memory block for the particular thread is being corrupted by the stack growth of some other thread/ or on the other hand it could be the logical error in the code.
To verify that, I want to track the changes done to the memory block, so that I can be 100% sure about my hypothesis.
Using mtrace, I am not able to achieve what I wanted.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What about keep track of a last modification date & name of modifier thread of that memory block.

Comment: @flybird Can you elaborate how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) ..
It's a professional tool for tracking running programs specializing in tracing heap allocations, threads variables and tracing child processes as well ..

If I understand your problem, then the `--verbose`, the `--check-stack-vars` and the `--read-var-info` options will be particularly helpful for you ..